# google button dose not work after deployment using firebase as database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-api

I make chat application based on firebase. When i run it on localhost it works, but when I deployed it the login button does not work correctly.

I opened oApi in google and I added the website to Authorized JavaScript origins also Authorized redirect URIs, but still not working.

[image: here is a image to my Authorized accounts]

here my code:

```
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithRedirect } from 'firebase/auth'
import React from 'react'
import {auth} from "../firebase"
const googleSignIn = () =>{
 const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
 signInWithRedirect (auth, provider)    
}

const SingIn = () => {
  return (
    <div className="" >
        <button className='login-btn'  onClick={googleSignIn}>Login with google </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SingIn
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: The error when I press that button does not happen anything, actually should appear the google window to choose which account to login but does not happen that.

Comment: I guess that you have errors in the browser's console

Answer (score 0):

It works I should To add my domain to Authotized domains in firebase (Authentication -> setting -> Authotized domains) then it should work .